# How can I make Chromium to not save history?

Tags: 16.04, chromium

So, I am using Chromium a little bit, and I am trying to make a way to prevent it from saving history. How can I do that? Also, I know about the incognito mode, but I don't want to use this every single time, I want chromium not to save history by default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Chrome Menu > Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Content Settings > Under Cookies and select Keep local data only until you quit your browser
2. Extension to clear history on exit.
3. Start in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it as Private Browser Window, it will not save any history , or go to settings and mark the option to delete after you close your browser.